# cx-Freeze disable target-dir delete

Tags: windows, python-3.7, setuptools, cx-freeze

Since cx-Freeze 6.6 the target dir will be deleted before build.
I build two different executables which use the same libs and other files.

So is there a way to disable the delete process before build?

Comment: https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/issues/1300

Comment: I've already read this.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible as you can see here:

https://github.com/marcelotduarte/cx_Freeze/blob/main/cx_Freeze/freezer.py#L124